# Android Button programmatic click

Tags: android, button, click

I have a button. I want to simulate a click on. `performClick()` does most of the job, but it doesn't do the button's animation. I tried `setPressed` and `setEnabled` as well, but no dice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call invalidate after the setPressed to force the view to redraw:

```
btn.setPressed(true);
btn.invalidate();
```

Comment: Yep, does what I want it to--but now how do I reset it? It gets stuck in the second drawable state, and neither invalidate() a second time nor setPressed(false) seems to bring it back.

Comment: You must set it to false and then invalidate again:  **btn.setPressed(false);  
btn.invalidate();**

Comment: Thanks a bunch! What I was doing wrong was putting it in the wrong place--I had to put the setpressed(false) in the ACTION_UP case, or else it executed everything to fast and you couldn't see the button change.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use tool [Monkey](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkey.html).