# Simulate Android button click programmatically

Tags: java, android

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553374/how-to-simulate-a-button-click-through-code-in-android) route,

```
View.performClick();
```

but it doesn't show the actual press of the button. I've also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887674/android-button-programmatic-click) method,

```
btn.setPressed(true);
btn.invalidate();
```

but, it just shows the button being pressed down. I've narrowed it down to this code, which presses down, and releases, but doesn't click. Am I missing something? How can I do a complete click as if though the user was clicking (monkeyrunner is not an option as of right now)

```
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_box);
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            btn.setPressed(true);
            btn.invalidate();
            Handler handler1 = new Handler();
            Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    btn.setPressed(false);
                    btn.invalidate();

                }
            };
            handler1.postDelayed(r1, 1000);

        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```

Comment: Try simulating a touch event (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7001356/1438733). I'd post it as an answer, but I'm not sure how well it'll work.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is fine. just add  `btn.performClick();` after the `invalidate();`

And for better look you can reduce the time of `handler1`.